# Does Stack Overflow celebrate its birthday?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

What is the birth date (first publish date) of Stack Overflow?

Does Stack Overflow celebrate its birthday?

- If yes, what event do we do?
- If no, can we celebrate it? Like we open a chat room and wish each other. Share our feelings about Stack Overflow.

I found [this article](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/one-year-of-stack-overflow/) where Jeff Atwood says July 31st, 2008 is its birthday but the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) does not clear it.

However today is SO's birthday. Happy birthday :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow says it was launched on 15th September 2008

Comment: Well, by Jeff's reckoning then, and depending on your timezone, Happy 15th (Unofficial, at the least) Birthday to SO today.

Answer (score 5):

Question 4 is the first one visible on the site. Revision 1 which is here https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4/1 was asked Jul 31 '08 at 21:42. Tempting as it seems to use this exact date and time, the user profile says this is a test account.

However, question 6 was asked at asked Jul 31 '08 at 22:08, https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6/1 and seems real enough.

In any case, July 31st sounds right. The official launch may have come later, but we could think of that as the announcement of the birth rather than the birth itself.

Comment: Question 1 was also posted July 31st: [MSE - What was the first question on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3991/what-was-the-first-question-on-so). You can see it if you have 10k rep.